# Weird integral equation with non convolution kernel

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, integral-equations

Let $f$ and $g$ two rugular functions. My question is the following:
Under what condition can we say that for given $g$, there exists $f$ such that we have:
$$\int\limits_0^1 {f(x - s,s)ds = g(x)} $$
Thank you.

Comment: Just take $f(x,y):= g(x+y)$. Then $f(x-s,s) = g(x)$.

Comment: Thanks sir. we are sur here that there is no uniqueness. How can I prove the existence of such solutions without taking any function of my choice?

Answer (score 2):

This type of functional equation resembles Wigner transforms in physics, except there one has lots of constraints and an infinite integration domain which result in unique solutions.

Here, without further information, the problem is hopelessly open-ended. For starters, it is not clear *why* you are writing *f* in this convoluted way, *if* you do not know something about the dependence of its two arguments which you are not telling. 
Why don't you simply redefine it as $f(x-s,s)\equiv h(x,s)$, in which case the enormity of the space of solutions is apparent?
$$
\int\limits_0^1  \!ds~~ h(x,s) = g(x) ~ .
$$

Typically, for regular functions, compare the respective Taylor expansions around 0,
$$
g(x)=  \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} g_j x^j ~,
$$
with 
$$
h(x,s)= h_0(x) +  \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}   x^j    \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} h_{j,k} ~k ~s^k ,    
$$
where the coefficient *k* is pulled out of the respective $h_{j,k}$ s for convenience in integration. That is to say,
$$ g(x)=  h_0(x) +  \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}   x^j  \left ( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} h_{j,k}  \right) .$$

At this point, you may go haywire... Slosh any degrees of freedom of the problem between $h_0 (0)$ and the series on the r.h.s.  Unless you had further constraints.

Comment: Thank you sir for responding. I see that in this case, the Fourier series are more useful here. What do you think?

Comment: Absolutely, a Fourier basis is the natural one. The question might be if you had some further input for the form of *f* , or if it is an arbitrary regular *h*...

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you sir. It was a  pleasure to me to discuss with you.

Comment: Thanks. To be sure, I know nothing about the domain of *x*, so I'd designate the Fourier coefficients of *h* by arbitrary functions of *x* .